# Android - The best way to keep the broadcastreceiver working

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, manifest, broadcast

I want my application to work and to listen for incoming Intents even if the activity is closed. What is the best way to do it?

I have a receiver registered on the manifest:

```
    <receiver
        android:name="com.farawayapp.background.Receiver"
        android:exported="false" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED" />
            <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_CHANGED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED" />

            <data android:scheme="package" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

And the `BroadcastReceiver` class is:

```
public class Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver implements Variables {

    CheckConexion cc;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context contxt, Intent intent) {

        // Cuando hay un evento, lo diferenciamos y hacemos una acción.

        if (intent.getAction().equals(SMS_RECEIVED)) {
            Sms sms = new Sms(null, contxt);
            sms.uploadNewSms(intent);
        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED)) {
            /*
             * try { new PhoneState(contxt).battery(intent.getIntExtra("level",
             * 0)); } catch (JSONException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
             */// Nothing at the moment
        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED)
                || intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_CHANGED)
                || intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED)) {
            Database db = new Database(contxt);
            if (db.open().Preferences(4)) {
                Uri data = intent.getData();
                new ListApps(contxt).import_app(intent, contxt, data,
                        intent.getAction());
            }
            db.close();
        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(
                ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION)) {
            cc = new CheckConexion(contxt);

            if (cc.isOnline()) {

                Database db = new Database(contxt);
                db.open();
                if (db.move() == 1) {
                    new UploadOffline(contxt);
                }
                db.close();

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks...

Comment: The system should "wake" your app up if it's not awake to receive the intent.

Comment: @KristopherMicinski How can I do it?

Comment: It already does that.  That's how it works.  You don't have to do anything.

Comment: @KristopherMicinski So it's not my problem?? :O

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4979790/run-broadcastreceiver-in-the-background-and-when-device-is-alseep

Comment: Are you sure you have the highest priority to catch those broadcasts..

Comment: What it's the best priority? @KristopherMicinski

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you register a `BroadcastReceiver` to receive broadcasts then it will be invoked even if user doesn't work with your application at the time (none of your application's activities is in foreground). Although, there are some pitfalls that you probably want to think about:

1. Most of the intents are not broadcasted when device is asleep. There are only several events that will wake up your device (such as incoming sms, incoming call, pushed notification from Google Cloud Messaging server, etc.). Thus, if want your application to do some work when device is asleep you should consider `AlarmManager` to set alarms that will regularly invoke your application.
2. If you want to do some work in background, you probably want to use `WakeLock` to prevent the device from sleeping (and CPU from turning off). This is a good sample from CommonWare that shows how to use `WakeLock` and provides you with nice library to ease your life: https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful. Although, you should be careful with `WakeLock` because it can drain battery.